# Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT' using mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve some data from the database, which need to be the top 10 of the agents with the highest score.

My Query:

```
SELECT AgentScores.agentID, 
       AgentScores.totalScore, 
       Agents.firstname, 
       Agents.lastname 
FROM AgentScores 
INNER JOIN Agents ON AgentScores.AgentId=Agents.Agent_id 
ORDER BY AgentScores.totalScore DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The inner joins are working. I've found the `SELECT TOP 10` sql statement but.. I want the 10 agents with the highest score and not the first 10 id's. As you can see I'm ordering on the totalscore.

Anyone has a clue how to fix this?

Error: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. ) )`

Thank you!

Comment: `"I want the 10 agents with the highest score and not the first 10 id's"` - That's what your `ORDER BY` clause is for.  You're not sorting by ID values, so why would it limit based on those?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to use TOP clause instead of LIMIT

```
SELECT TOP 10 AgentScores.agentID, AgentScores.totalScore, Agents.firstname, Agents.lastname FROM AgentScores INNER JOIN Agents ON AgentScores.AgentId=Agents.Agent_id ORDER BY AgentScores.totalScore DESC
```

Comment: but why is that so ?

Answer (score 15):

In order to limit rows in MSSQL, you have to use `SELECT TOP 10` .... instead of `LIMIT 10` (limit is a MySQL clause, not MSSQL)

Comment: @drmavelous But.. doesn't it just grab the first 10 id's in the database? Like, what if I have 100 agents and id 87 has the highest score.. Doesn't it just only order the first 10 id's?

Comment: No, as it will read from the ORDER BY clause and select the top 10 matching that

Comment: no, you keep the order by clause as is, so it will return the first 10 records based on the order specified in the order by clause.

Comment: "In a SELECT statement, always use an ORDER BY clause with the TOP clause. This is the only way to predictably indicate which rows are affected by TOP." [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)