# Incorrect Syntax - LIMIT - SQL Syntax 2008

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sql-limit

Hi I am using SQl Server 2008 and need to limit in my SQL query!

I was told to look at this code to get an idea:

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Col1, Col2, ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol1, SortCol2, ...) AS RowNum
    FROM Table
    WHERE <whatever>
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= @Offset
AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit
```

I need to implement this into my current statement which wont work in SQL 2008.

```
$strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM BlogItem WHERE Blog_Live=1 LIMIT '.$rowsperpage.' OFFSET '.$offset.''; $objQuery = mssql_query($strSQL)
or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
```

Can anyone advise me on the way to do this? As looking at the first lot of code I am just lost!

Thanks

Comment: Google and learn about the `TOP` keyword in SQL Server.

Comment: mssql doesn't have `limit`, it has `select top x`-type syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT' using mssql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704424/incorrect-syntax-near-limit-using-mssql)