# Syntax error in SQL Server query with LIMIT keyword

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

I am trying to run this query, but I am getting an error

> syntax error near keyword 'limit'

SQL query:

```sql
select * 
from messages as msg 
where "+"(SELECT date from messages where date between
 msg.firsttime and msg.lasttime and receiver is null limit 1) 
limit 5
```

Where is my mistake except 'limit' keyword.

```
Select top 5 * 
from messages as msg 
where (
    SELECT top 1 date 
    from messages 
    where date between msg.firsttime and msg.lasttime 
      and receiver is null
)
```

Comment: `WHERE "+"(SELECT...` Doesn't make any sense; what is that trying to achieve? Also there is no `LIMIT` operator/keyword in T-SQL. T-SQL uses [`TOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT' using mssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704424/incorrect-syntax-near-limit-using-mssql)

Comment: What is the server? Different servers accept different syntaxes. For example MySQL and PostGresql use `SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT xx`, but MS SQL Server uses `SELECT TOP xx ... FROM ...`.

I am also not sure about the `"+"(...`. What are you trying to use the `"+"` for?

Comment: @Larnu is correct. 

Just a hint for SQL errors: Pretend that the server is a very accurate child. It's fast but not smart. If you carefully read the error message and take it at it's most basic possible meaning, it will often tell you what's wrong. 

In this case, the first error means "I don't understand LIMIT or possibly what's in front of it". This is because LIMIT is MySQL/MariaDB syntax, not SQL Server. 

Once you fix that by replace the LIMIT with a "TOP nnnn" clause, you'll probably find a new complaint about the "+", which is invalid also.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

First up is `LIMIT`. **`LIMIT` is not ANSI-standard SQL.** It's a proprietary extension used in MySQL and SQLite. SQL Server has it's own proprietary extension for this  (`SELECT TOP`), but it also supports the actual standard using [`OFFSET`/`FETCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned).

Next is the `WHERE` clause. This query has a nested `SELECT` statement in the main `WHERE` clause to find a `date` value... and then **doesn't compare it to anything**. There's no conditional operation. You need to do some kind of boolean comparison with this result.

Comment: Yes, of course I understand limit keyword. But ı didnt see error near the where clause

Comment: You need an expression like this: where date = (Your_Subquery)