# I have to calculate the median of a series of values on sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck with this problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem?isFullScreen=true

This is the solution I wrote.

```
SELECT LAT_N
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N ASC
LIMIT FLOOR(COUNT(LAT_N)/2),1;
```

It seems reasoning to me, but i continue to get this error
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(COUNT(LAT_N)/2),1' at line 4.

Comment: Can you use `COUNT` in a `LIMIT` clause?

Comment: All questions should be self-contained so please update your question with what you are trying to achieve - rather than linking to an external site

Comment: @tadman isn't it possible?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me you are using a mySQL syntax on a SQL server
The solution probably implies using TOP instead of LIMIT
please see :
[Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT' using mssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704424/incorrect-syntax-near-limit-using-mssql)

Comment: A SQL Server (Like in: Microsoft SQL Server) does not give errors like: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;.....`